# I've added a variable to CSSStyleDeclaration prototype, but can't modify it

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototype

I don't really understand prototypes, so it might be my fault, but theorically if I add a variable to a prototype, I will be able to change it in its instances, right? 
Here the code:

```
    <head>
        <script>
            CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype["foo"] = "something";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="foo:'maybe'" id ="myId"></div>
        <script>
            var el = document.getElementById("myId");
            console.log(el.style.foo);
        </script>
    </body>
```

The console returns "something", why?

Comment: If it returns `"something"`, it means it was modified 'cause it's original value was `"maybe"`...right? I can't see where it's not modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `foo` is not a standard property, so

- When you set [`cssText`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-csstext), the declaration is ignored
- Since it has been ignored, [`getPropertyValue`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) would not have been able to retrieve the value.
- Instead, you attempt to get it via a [camel-cased getter](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute), but these getters only exist for [supported CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#supported-css-property).

However, on browsers that support [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), you could use them:

```js
function getFoo(el) {
  return getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--foo');
}
snippet.log("body: " + getFoo(document.body));
snippet.log("#myId: " + getFoo(document.getElementById('myId')));
```

```css
* {
  --foo: 'something';
}
```

```html
<div style="--foo: 'maybe'" id="myId"></div>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 --><script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been trying with custom css prefixes and camel cased properties too :D Now I got it